# Рендерит только первый <li> innerHTML. Нужно вывести полноценный список

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую `innerHTML` пытаюсь отобразить в `li` список из 200 title.
Но, при этом отображает только 1.
Подскажите в чем причина может быть?

```js
const listLi = document.querySelector('.listli');

const getApi = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  const result = await response.json();
  result.map(el => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      listLi.innerHTML = el.title;
    }
  })
};

getApi();
```

```html
<ol>
  <li class="listli"></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: А что по твоему происходит на каждой итерации в этом месте `listLi.innerHTML = el.title`? И откуда там вообще списку взяться, когда элемент только один?

Comment: Очевидно, в том, что у вас в html-коде один-единственный элемент li, а новых элементов вы нигде даже не пытаетесь создавать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте

```js
const todo_el = document.querySelector('#todo');

const getApi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  const result = await response.json();
  result.map(el => {
    let li_el = document.createElement("li");
    li_el.textContent = el.title;  
    todo_el.appendChild(li_el);
  })
};

getApi();
```

```html
<body>
   <ol id="todo"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо!) Получилось!

Comment: @salco202020, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Можете подсказать, зачем создавать текстовую ноду?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, если использовать текстовую ноду, то содержимое из `el.title` будет воспринято именно как строка, а не как кусок html :)

Comment: @gil9red, то есть, оно уберет все html теги или будет как innerText? Если как второе, то смысл тогда?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, нет, теги будут отображаться как есть, без их рендеринга. Поменяйте строку с `textnode` например на `let textnode = document.createTextNode("<a href='https://123.com'>" + el.title + "</a>");` и увидите этот же тег, а не ссылку с текстом из `el.title`

Comment: @gil9red, тогда в чем разница между innerText? Я не пытаюсь "докопаться", мне правда хочется понять)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, а, наверное, не будет, мне показалось вы имели ввиду innerHTML,что у соседнего ответа используется :)

Comment: @OliverPatterson, спасибо, за вопросы :) Думаю, лучше поменять ответ и вместо `createTextNode` использовать что-то аналогичное, но проще выглядящее :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<body>
   <ol class="listli" />
</body>

const list = document.querySelector('.listli');

const getApi = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  const result = await response.json();
  result.forEach(el => {
    const li = document.createElement('li')
    li.innerHTML = el.title;
    list.append(li)     
  })
};

getApi();
```

Comment: Спасибо!) Получилось!